# Dynamic form with TextInput's don't fill

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I have Laravel Filament 3 dynamic form. With `Select` I select a specific `ModuleType`, which can consist of multiple `Element`'s.
Then `TextInput`'s appear with `Element`'s data.

For some reason, the code only works if I set `Select` with `default` value.

```
public function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Section::make()->schema([
                Select::make("id")
                    ->label("Module Type")
                    ->required()
                    ->options(function () {
                        return ModuleType::all()->pluck("full_name", "id");
                    })

                    //->default(1)

                    ->live()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->preload(),
                Fieldset::make("elements")
                    ->label("Elements")
                    ->schema(function (Get $get) {
                        if ($get("id")) {
                            return $this->getElements($get("id"));
                        } else {
                            return [];
                        }
                    })
                    ->columns(10)
                    ->hidden(
                        fn(Get $get): bool => !$get("id") ||
                            ModuleType::findOrFail(
                                $get("id")
                            )->elements->count() == 0
                    ),
            ]),
        ])
        ->statePath("data")
        ->model(ModuleType::class);
}
```

With `default` state
[image]

Without `default` state
[image]

Full code [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OlyaK95/livewire-check-elements/main/app/Filament/Pages/CheckElements.php).

I asked my question [here](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/11029) too.